# How do I set an IronPython ctypes c_char_p pointer to an absolute address manually?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, ironpython

I need to set the address to which a character pointer points to as an absolute value.

In many Python implementations (CPyhton 2.x, CPython 3.x, PyPy & ActivePython, ...) this can be done using:

```
>>> c_char_p(0xcafebabe)
c_char_p(3405691582)
>>>
```

in IronPython:

```
>>> c_char_p(0xcafebabe)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected char pointer, got long
>>>
```

IronPython does not attempt to set the address of the pointer, but treats the argument as content and then returns a type conflict. However, the functionality of the other Python distributions mentioned above does not apply to IronPython.

What can I do to set a `c_char_p` to an absolute address in IronPython?

The background for my question:

I have developed a DLL which is written in Delphi.
The purpose of the DLL is to have an external interface to a Delphi application.
I can control the application via the DLL in C and C++ successfully.
Customers requested for a more convenient solution -> they want to control the application with Python.
I've developed a Python package that's actually much easier to use.
All DLL functions have to be called with a pointer to the same type of structure which represents a device.
The first function to call is the DLL's Init function which initialises the structure with default values.
Unfortunately the design of the structure lacks an important item, that is the configuration of RS232 parameters,
because support for RS232 devices was not planned in the first version of the DLL.
To still provide RS232 support, the DLL has been modified to use the absolute address of an existing char* in the device structure as a signal.
If this char* has the absolute address 0xCAFEBABE, the DLL parses a configuration string that has been put into another char* of the structure.
This ugly solution works very well and the attributes of the structure did not have to be changed.
Everything works fine when controlling the DLL/application with CPyhton 2.x, CPython 3.x, PyPy & ActivePython.
Unfortunately IronPython reports an error when trying to set the pointer to the absolute address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, *IPython* is more restrictive when it comes to addresses, and conversions must be performed manually. This can done via [[Python 2]: ctypes.**cast**(*obj, type*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
import ctypes


CharPtr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)


def main():
    pchar0 = ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_char_p("Dummy text"), CharPtr)  # Create an object that will yield a valid memory address
    buf_addr = ctypes.addressof(pchar0.contents) # Raw buffer address
    print("Raw buffer address: 0x{:016X}".format(buf_addr))

    cp0 = ctypes.cast(buf_addr, ctypes.c_char_p)
    print("cp0 ({:s}) value: {:s}\n".format(cp0.__class__.__name__, cp0.value))

    cp1 = ctypes.c_char_p(buf_addr)
    print("cp1 ({:s}) value: {:s}".format(cp1.__class__.__name__, cp1.value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055118583]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Raw buffer address: 0x00000000036D0690
> cp0 (c_char_p) value: Dummy text
>
> cp1 (c_char_p) value: Dummy text
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055118583]> "c:\Install\IronLanguages\IronPython\02.07.09\net45\ipy.exe" code.py
> Python 2.7.9 (IronPython 2.7.9 (2.7.9.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit)) on cli
>
> Raw buffer address: 0x00000209BFF2E860
> cp0 (c_char_p) value: Dummy text
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code.py", line 24, in <module>
>   File "code.py", line 18, in main
> TypeError: expected char pointer, got long
> ```

**Notes**:

- *pchar0*'s purpose is just to get a **valid** memory address (*buf_addr*) which points to a `char*` (as *0xCafeBabe* has no meaning in my *Python* process)
- *cp1* (take them in reversed order) is the problem statement: trying to create a `ctypes.c_char_p` from a memory address (according to the latest question edit: that is filled with a `char*` by some routines in a *.dll* (which must be loaded in the current process))

  - That works (according to the question) in *CPython*, but raises the *TypeError* in *IPython*
- *cp0* is the problem solution: trying to create a `ctypes.c_char_p` from **the same** memory address

  - That works in *CPython* **and** *IPython*

Comment: In short, your solution for this in IronPython is: ctypes.cast (0xcafebabe, ctypes.c_char_p) . When I run it on a 64 bit IronPython, I get c_char_p ('') and everything seems to be ok (I assume that the string from this address cannot be read but I really only need the address in that pointer and NOT the content where the pointer points to), but on a 32 bit IronPython I get: OverflowError (in fact the overflow only happens when the address is 2^^31 and greater).

Comment: I exposed a solution that behaves identically on *CPython* and *IPython* (and behaves just like your attempt that works in *CPython* - with the same address). This was / is what the question is all about. What's in that address is irrelevant from the question *PoV*, as it wasn't exposed, but given your code it's a `char*`. As I specified in comments from the code, the *pchar0* object is only created to get a valid *buf_addr* (which contains a **valid and accessible** `char*`), because *0xCafeBabe* is meaningless.

Comment: you are right from the point of view that the Python process has to read the **content** of the `c_char_p` but (as I mentioned in the background of my question) the the `c_char` in this case acts as a **signal** from the Python process **towards** the DLL (for the special value 0xCAFEBABE of this pointer the DLL is triggered to read in an RS232 configuration). Your answer let me assume that there is actually no way for IronPython to do this job (the use of this trick was very helpful to maintain full backwards compatibility of the DLL). Thank you for your helpful support.

Comment: No. the answer's point is that everything that can be done from regular *Python* can also be done from *IPython*. "*What can I do to set a `c_char_p` to an absolute address in IronPython?*" Just what the answer instructed. The 2nd paragraph doesn't change anything. It just adds some info that doesn't seem relevant at 1st glance, and it might be very clear to you, but for other people may not. It might be subject to another question though. Note that the *c\_char\p* is a ***Python* wrapper** over the 'char*', it's not the same thing.

Comment: I am fully with you: your answer to my question is absolutely correct. The point is that my question was not specific enough.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it was a problem in the communication protocol :). Regarding your 2nd paragraph, as I said it might be the subject of another question (as I still don't see the connection to this one yet - although it's OK to place context in questions). But I don't know what anyone else other than you (an probably your other colleagues that work on your project), would understand what the problem is, from the text alone, so you should add some code samples as well ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: I noticed you created another question. Could you please mark this one as resolved (by marking the answer as a solution), so that it's visible to others as well?