# How do I set an IronPython ctypes c_char_p pointer to an absolute address that is not a valid memory address to read from?

Tags: pointers, ctypes, ironpython

In IronPython 2.7.9 I need to set a `c_char_p` to the absolute address `0xCAFEBABE`. This 'address' will **not** be a valid memory address to read from but it acts as a magic word to trigger something (you can read the background of why I have to use a char* without content in my question at '[How do I set an IronPython ctypes c_char_p pointer to an absolute address manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118583)' where the original question was not good enough for my problem). In addition I am only allowed to use the 32bit version of the IronPython interpreter since I have to load a 32bit DLL.

```
from ctypes import *
class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("config", c_char_p),
                ("magicnumber",  c_char_p)]

mystruct = MyStruct()
mystruct.config      = "my RS232 configuration"
mystruct.magicnumber = cast(0xCAFEBABE, c_char_p)
```

Unfortunately the last assignment raises an `OverflowError`.
Other Python implementations (CPyhton 2.x, CPython 3.x, PyPy & ActivePython, ...) can do this job without any problems.

What the assignment of the attribute `magicnumber` should do is that the Python interpreter shall write the 32bit address `0xCAFEBABE` into the right memory address of the pointer inside the structure (what many other Python distributions except of IronPython can do).

The tight coupling of IronPython to the .NET framework makes IronPython interesting to many developers who want to use it in combination with other .NET languages.

May be this task is not possible with IronPython?
I would be glad to have at least a reliable answer to it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Things are a lot more clearer. So that's not an address. The *.dll* (or whoever) will always interpret the *magicnumber* field as a 32bit value? How is this structure defined in the other end (*Delphi*)?

Comment: You asked the right question that gave me the right idea! Inside the Delphi DLL the structure contains a regular `char*`. So far the Python structure also contains a regular `c_char_p` because strings have to be sent to the DLL. But from now on I will declare it as a `c_int` on the Python side. When this field is accessed by writing a string to it I will allocate a buffer and set the buffer's address to the `c_int` field. A write of `0xCAFEBABE` into this field is already valid so there is nothing more todo in this case.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to suggest `ctypes.c_uint`, or maybe `ctypes.c_char * 4`. But I also wanted to point out that on *64bit* there might be some unpleasant surprises (that;s why I asked how the *.dll* will interpret the member).

Comment: IronPython 64bit does not work anyway since the DLL is 32bit and cannot be loaded in a 64bit environment as far as I know. So there can be no side effects from the wrong environment.

Comment: Correct. But when writing code I like to think ahead (as I switch frequently between architectures and *OS*es), and e.g. for this specific case I'd like to make code *64bit* compliant, so that when the *64bit* *.dll* will be available (ever), to avoid the need of massive redesign, or running into all kinds of crashes. But anyway this is not so important :)

Comment: yes, we already check `platform.architecture()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain an overall solution to this question for all Python implementation we should **not** declare the structure attribute as of its original type `c_char_p` but as `c_uint`.

This implies to wrap access to this attribute to handler functions that must take care of the modified type.

A write access to this attribute with a string as the argument has to allocate an apropriate buffer and store the string into the buffer.

Then the **address** of the buffer is written into this `c_uint` attribute. A write access with the special flag `0xCAFEBABE` can directly be written into the attribute's new `c_uint` type.

A read access should only return the content of the buffer since data transfers via this attribute into the Python code is not intended for this attribute.

This has been verified and works flawlessly.